# Azure Active Directory warning the security token service signing certificate validation failed ID1118

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I'm following this guide here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151790.aspx

At the section

```
The tool lists various authority types you can use to outsource authentication. In our specific case, we are interested in using a Business Identity Provider: click on the corresponding entry, second option from the top.
```

And it asks me to enter the path to the STS metadata document and I get the following error

```
warning the security token service signing certificate validation failed ID1118
```

Has anybody done this before? What's going on here? Let me know if you need more information I'm stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of the Identity&Access Tool performs a 'ChainTrust' validation each signing certificate found in the metadata. If any certificates fail the validation, this warning pops up. The metadata is retrieved over https when the channel must show proof of the private key, you should be OK. I would check the metadata to see that it looks correct.

Comment: you cannot do much it even if it really is broken, because you cannot control Token signing certificate of Azure AD, nor the HTTPS certificate of the Azure AD STS. Last but no least, there is a BIG NOTE on top of document with statement that this article is outdated and users shall look into other sample code. I've been using the tool and the AD STS with no issues, but in 2012 ... nowadays I use VS 2013 and what is described in the referenced newer article...